# Compilando Unity para Tablet

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity-5, unity2d

Como eu faço para compilar meu jogo Unity para tablet ?
Preciso mudar algum parametro de tamanho como faço para o mobile ou WEBGL já atenderia ?

Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Não, é a mesma build que farias para android. Em referencia ao tamanho, deves apenas com se atentar ao canvas e a configuração de resolução na tela de **Game** *(Ctrl+2)*, setando a resolução que tem o tablet target. Configurando este aspect/resolution, na tela **Game**, tua *Main Camera* já ficará adequado ao que verás no teu dispositivo.

Referente ao canvas, no próprio há uma opção do qual lhe ajuda ao trabalhar com resoluções diferentes, que é o caso do *Scale With Screen Size*, no componente de *Canvas Scaler*, veja qual das configurações de *Screen Match Mode* funcionam melhor para você e faça o build conforme faria para qualquer Dispositivo Android.

Segue um link para auxiliar na build Android: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nb62z3J4A_A

Mais informações referente as configurações de canvas responsivo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N7_fRXlrUj4

Mais informações sobre aspect e resolutions: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yhSzfynM4aA

Answer (score -1):

Olá. A compilação para tablet é uma compilação Android como qualquer outra. Você só precisa definir o "platform" no "build settings" para "Android" e, claro, ter instalado o Android SDK e demais dependências.

A compilação WebGL também roda em Android (smartphone ou tablet), mas a Unity não dá suporte a isso. Um dos principais problemas é em relação ao teclado virtual nativo, que não é exibido (você precisaria implementar um interno na Unity).

Espero ter ajudado.